# Do rocks (stone/iron deposites) come back after being destroyed?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I destroyed most of the stones on my island. Do these come back after a while or should I start over?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, one [respawns](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21188404/rocks-move-break-respawn-location) each day until they eventually all return.